# Finding the pattern in number of (next and up) nearest neighbours of $N$ points on a circle

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

The question is rather vague (I couldn't phrase it more clearly though) so let me explain. Say you have a circle, and you put four equidistant points on it. You then have two types of neighbours: nearest neighbours and second nearest neighbours. This would be $1,2; 2,3; 3,4; 4,1$ and $1,3; 2,4$. Third nearest neighbours don't exist, or at least I don't count them because they are already nearest neighbours. So in this case of 4 points we have two different types of neighbours, the first group contains 4 and the second group contains 2 elements.

Now, my question is, is there a system for $N$ equidistant points on a circle? It doesn't seem obvious to me, but it should be there. Lets take the example of 6: nearest neighbours are $1,2; 2,3; 3,4; 4,5; 5,6; 6,1$, 2nd NN are $1,3; 2,4; 3,5; 4,6; 5,1; 6,2$, 3rd nearest are $1,4; 2,5; 3,6$.

Okay, so now there's 3 groups. The first two have the same size, the last is half. If we do the same for 8 (I'll leave out the numbers) you get 4 groups and the last group has size 4. So to me the pattern seems to be you have N/2 types of neighbours, the first N-1 of which have size N, and the last has size N/2. Does this work for general $N$? I haven't tried for odd; maybe here one has to use the $floor$ function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even $N$, given one point, there are $N-1$ other points, which is an odd number.  There are two at each distance up to $\frac N2-1$ and one at distance $\frac N2$

For odd $N$, given one point, there are $N-1$ other points, which is an even number.  There are two at each distance up to $\frac {N-1}2$

Comment: Okay, yes, I see what you mean. I'm still not entirely sure however how to go from there. Lets take N is even, and distance 1. So there are two points at distance 1 from the first point. But also for the second, etcetera. How can one then quickly count the total number of unique nearest neighbours? I suppose this is the first time I use the word unique out loud. For even it feels like this would be $2\times N / 2$ for all but the furthest distance, for which it is $N/2$

Comment: Not quite. As I said, there are two points at each distance up to $N/2-1$, which accounts for $N-2$ points. One of the others is the one you are counting from, the other is the one at distance $N/2$

Comment: Yes, I see. One point, then two at each distance up to, and the final one. It might be that I'm just not thinking clearly, but how does one translate into the number of points at a certain distance (say, 1) in total, in the system? So in the sense of unique pairs at a certain distance. The total number of points at a distance 1 from each point is two, but multiplying by the number of points makes you double count.

Comment: The number of pairs at any distance less than $N/2$ is $N$.  As you say, each of $N$ points has two points that distance away, but you have counted each pair twice.  $2N/2=N$  Another way to see the same thing is to define that you always start from some point and go clockwise.  Then you have $N$ places to start and for each one you have one unique pair.

Comment: Great! Perhaps I should have added some context to the question; the goal is simplifying a sum over $i /neq j$ in a system with periodic boundary conditions, where this helps a lot.